# How to know when and witch function was call when cookie value changed

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have an application that has a bug that, after ~30min, a cookie named Customer as set as undefined.

[image]

My question is: t**here is any way that I could know which function was called to set the cookie value as undefined**? Can be a **tool** or a javascript **script** or even an google chrome **debug tool**.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Well you know every place that you are setting the cookie and you are setting it to some value, why not just trigger a breakpoint if that value is undefined, using `debugger` in an if statement for example

Comment: Do you have access to the whole codebase?

Comment: @NickA I did that and i found out that my code is not calling the `document.cookie`. I'm afraid that could be a libraries or something that is doing that.

Comment: @Adriano I "don't have access" to some libraries code. Of course the javascript is open source. But still I don't have acess

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to know what function changed a given value, therefore the only way I can think of is to go by exclusion. Try to remove all the external js from the head and re-add them one by one; and see if the issue persists.